# AngularJS stop updating scope variable

Tags: angularjs

I have a $scope.taskList which contains a number of task objects. and I have a form where I can update task. first I select task then load it's data to the form. Do the change and after I press the save button object in the list is updated. everything looks good. but right after the save, if I keep changing values in the form data in the list is updated on change (without needing to click save)

my submit function looks like that:

```
$scope.submitTaskForm = function() {
        if ($scope.createTaskForm.$valid) {
            $http({
                method: "post",
                url: '/admin/json/manage/task',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
                data: $scope.task
            }).success(function (response) {

                if (response.status == 'success') {
                    var index = 0,
                        updated = false;
                    $scope.task = response.task;
                    while ((index < $scope.taskList.length) && (updated == false)) {
                        if ($scope.taskList[index].id == $scope.task.id) {
                            $scope.taskList[index] = $scope.task;
                            updated = true;
                        }
                        index++;
                    }
                    if (updated == false) {
                        $scope.taskList.push($scope.task);
                        $scope.itemAdded();
                    }
                    alert('Successfully saved');
                } else {
                    alert(response.message);
                }
            });
        }
    };
```

I'm sure it's because of this line `$scope.taskList[index] = $scope.task;` but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: i am not sure but try this: $scope.taskList[index] = angular.copy($scope.task)

Comment: agree, most likely angular's two-way biding is working.

Comment: Thanks it works! take your comment as an answer and I'll accept it